# Wagtail vs Mezzanine, which is better for building a customised CMS?

Tags: django, wagtail, mezzanine

Wagtail and Mezzanine are good open source CMS platforms. But, which one is better to be extended and used to build a Django web app with CMS included?

Comment: @KevinL. Yes. Thanks. I am looking for more details.

Comment: Great do let us know your conclusion by answering your own post later

Answer (score 0):

Well you should probably choose the framework that you are the most familiar with. Otherwise, this article talking about wagtail might be useful.

> your Wagtail app is just a simple, vanilla Django app and as such very
>   easy to integrate with custom models, apps, etc as you build it out.

[Link](http://www.djangopaths.com/why-did-i-choose-wagtail/)